# Mocking an instance within a class

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

Good evening,

I'm trying to create some tests for the below typescript class. I'm trying to create a test so that I can verify that the internal `BroadcastChannel` has its `postMessage` method called but I'm unable to create the relevant spy to do this. I'm guessing it's because I'm not attaching the spy to the actual instance inside the class but I'm unsure.

```
export class BroadcastChannelService<T> {
  private readonly broadcastChannel: BroadcastChannel;

  constructor(name: CHANNEL_NAMES) {
    this.broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel(name);
  }

  postMessage = (msg: T) => {
    this.broadcastChannel.postMessage(msg);
  }
}
```

below is the test that I have so far

```
import { BroadcastChannel } from 'broadcast-channel';

import { BroadcastChannelService } from '../../services';

jest.mock('broadcast-channel');
const mockedBroadcastChannel = BroadcastChannel as jest.Mocked<typeof BroadcastChannel>;

describe('BroadcastChannelService', () => {
  let subject: BroadcastChannelService<string>;

  describe('constructor', () => {
    afterAll(() => {
      jest.resetAllMocks();
    });

    test('is successful', () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      subject = new BroadcastChannelService<string>('GOOGLE_AUTH');
      expect(mockedBroadcastChannel).toBeCalledWith('GOOGLE_AUTH');
      expect(mockedBroadcastChannel).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });

  describe('postMessage', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      subject = new BroadcastChannelService('GOOGLE_AUTH');
      subject.postMessage('Hello World');
    });

    afterAll(() => {
      jest.resetAllMocks();
    });

    test('is successful', () => {
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So the trick was using `spyOn` with `mockedBroadcastChannel.prototype`

```
import { BroadcastChannel } from 'broadcast-channel';
import { BroadcastChannelService } from '../../services';

jest.mock('broadcast-channel');
const mockedBroadcastChannel = BroadcastChannel as jest.Mocked<typeof BroadcastChannel>;

describe('BroadcastChannelService', () => {
  let subject: BroadcastChannelService<string>;

  describe('constructor', () => {
    test('is successful', () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      subject = new BroadcastChannelService<string>('GOOGLE_AUTH');
      expect(mockedBroadcastChannel).toBeCalledWith('GOOGLE_AUTH');
      expect(mockedBroadcastChannel).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });

  describe('postMessage', () => {
    test('is successful', () => {
      const postMessageSpy = jest.spyOn(mockedBroadcastChannel.prototype, 'postMessage');
      subject = new BroadcastChannelService<string>('GOOGLE_AUTH');
      subject.postMessage('Hello World');
      expect(postMessageSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(postMessageSpy).toBeCalledWith('Hello World');
    });
  });
});
```